# Is the inverse of the position operator compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be the position operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, defined by $(Xf)(x)=xf(x)$ on a suitable domain of definition.

We can then obtain an operator $\frac{1}{|X|}$ by two (equivalent, I think) ways:

- Apply the function $\frac{1}{|x|}$ on $X$ via functional calculus.
- Get $|X|$ by the polar decomposition and then take its inverse.

Now to my question:
**Is the operator $\frac{1}{|X|}$ compact?**

Context: I am working through the proof of Theorem 11 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9411052) on page 50/51, and if I understand it correctly, they make use of the fact, that $\frac{1}{|X|}$ is compact.

Comment: $1/|X|$ explicitly acts as $$\left(\frac1{|X|}f\right)(x) = \frac1{|x|}f(x)$$
so its spectrum is the image of the function $x \mapsto \frac1{|x|}$, which is $(0, +\infty)$. So I guess the answer is no.

Comment: $\frac1{|X|}$ is unbounded, definitely not compact. Even if you are looking at something $L^2(1,\infty)$ so that $\frac1{|X|}$ is bounded it still cannot be compact. You can see this since the operator is self-adjoint and compact self-adjoint operators decompose into eigenvectors, which is not the case here.